# Generalised Gauss sums

Tags: finite-fields, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum

Let $\chi$ be a non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo an odd prime $p$
and let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial. We define the generalised Gauss sum $$ G(\chi, f):=\sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p^*}
\chi(y) \left(\frac{f(y)}{p}\right).$$ Under which conditions for $f$ can we prove that
$$ G(\chi,f)\ll \deg(f) \sqrt{p},$$
with an absolute implied constant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\eta$ be a generator of the character group $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}_p^*}$. Therefore $\chi=\eta^k$ for some integer $k$, $0<k<p-1$ and the Legendre symbol is equal to $\eta^{(p-1)/2}$. Therefore
$$
G(\chi,f)=\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_p}\eta(y^kf(y)^{(p-1)/2}).
$$

The general Weil bound for multiplicative character sums says that the sum
$$
S(g)=\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_p}\eta(g(y))
$$
is in the non-trivial cases bounded by
$$
|S(g)|\le (d-1)\sqrt p,
$$
where $d$ is the number of zeros of $g(y)$ in its splitting field over $\Bbb{F}_p$. The sum is trivial, if $g(y)$ is of the form $g(y)=c h(y)^{p-1}$
for some $c\in\Bbb{F}_p$ and $h(y)\in\Bbb{F}_p[y]$.

Obviously the number of zeros of $g(y)$ is bounded from above by $\deg g$. 
In your case the number of zeros of $y^kf(y)^{(p-1)/2}$ is bounded from above by
$\deg f+1$ (add one for the power of $y$ factor, unless $f(0)=0$). Therefore

> When your sums are non-trivial they are bounded as guessed. With absolute constant $1$ and without the logarithmic factor.

The sum is trivial, if $y^kf(y)^{(p-1)/2}$ is a constant times a $(p-1)$th power of a polynomial (modulo $p$). This happens for example when $f(y)=y$ and $\chi$ is also the Legendre character.

Comment: My $\chi$ is multiplicative, not additive. So your comments are not related to my question.

Comment: Ouch. Sorry about that. You see that I rarely use Dirichlet characters :-). I will rethink this tomorrow (too late an hour here, and Imma bit drunk also). In principle the case of two multiplicative characters is simpler, because they can be combined to one. Also, the key parameter is the number of zeros rather than degree, so something useful will follow from the Weil bound.

Comment: Ok, the edited answer is what I was looking for, thanks !